# Why is Unity 3d game closing after splash screen?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I was using Unity 3D 2018. But 2018 doesn't support Android SDK API 29. Because of that I upgraded my version to 2019.2.9f1

I created my project in 2018 version. And now, I'm using 2019 version for my project.

My problem started after the update. Game closes after the splash screen.
I've been trying for a long day for fix this problem.

I tried those things;

- il2cpp and mono both of them doesn't help. Problem is not because of the il2cpp. (All the Internet are saying because of il2cpp but not for me, mono doesn't work to)
- Trying Android backup to false (with Android manifest file)
- Trying update all assets

I tried everything I saw in the Internet. But nothing works.

```
10-24 22:12:28.810: D/Launcher.CellLayout(2146): touch item:ShortcutInfo, id=246, itemType=0, user=UserHandle{0}, mIconType=0, mTitle=Şahin Uzayda, mLabel=Şahin Uzayda, pkgName=com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda, className=com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity, screenId=6, container=-100, cellX=1, cellY=0, spanX=1, spanY=1, isLandscapePos=false
10-24 22:12:28.926: I/Timeline(2146): Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:15228423 intent:Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity bnds=[331,101][499,269] (has extras) }
10-24 22:12:28.929: I/ActivityManager(1663): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity bnds=[331,101][499,269] (has extras)} from uid 10028 on display 0
10-24 22:12:28.937: I/ANDR-IOP(1663): MIUI-IOP pkg_name = com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda PID = -1
10-24 22:12:28.959: I/ActivityManager(1663): Start proc 22887:com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda/u0a241 for activity com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity caller=com.miui.home
10-24 22:12:28.960: D/PowerKeeper.Event(3220): notifyAMProcStart processName: 10241 reason: com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda, pid:0
10-24 22:12:28.960: I/ANDR-IOP(1663): MIUI-IOP pkg_name = com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda PID = 22887
10-24 22:12:29.048: D/GameBoosterService(2606): onGameStatusChange foreground:ForegroundInfo{mForegroundPackageName='com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda', mForegroundUid=10241, mForegroundPid=22887, mLastForegroundPackageName='com.miui.home', mLastForegroundUid=10028, mLastForegroundPid=2146, mMultiWindowForegroundPackageName='null', mMultiWindowForegroundUid=-1, mFlags=1}
10-24 22:12:29.133: D/AccessibilityManager(22887): current package=com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda, accessibility manager mIsFinalEnabled=false, mOptimizeEnabled=false, mIsUiAutomationEnabled=false, mIsInterestedPackage=false
10-24 22:12:29.264: I/ActivityManager(1663): Displayed com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity: +317ms
10-24 22:12:29.265: I/Timeline(1663): Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{216ffa0 u0 com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t136} time:15228762
10-24 22:12:29.265: D/PowerKeeper.Event(3220): notifyActivityLaunchTime: com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity totalTime: 317
10-24 22:12:29.273: I/Unity(22887): ApplicationInfo com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda version 2.5 build 0682396a-d6c8-44ad-b159-8749835ed3df
10-24 22:12:29.280: I/WindowManager(1663): Destroying surface Surface(name=Starting com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2045 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:897 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1460 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2635 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2593 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2462 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2457 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:202 
10-24 22:12:29.295: I/WindowManager(1663): Screen frozen for +329ms due to Window{288d3f7 u0 Starting com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda}
10-24 22:12:32.156: E/AndroidRuntime(22887): Process: com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda, PID: 22887
10-24 22:12:32.163: W/ActivityManager(1663):   Force finishing activity com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
10-24 22:12:32.238: I/WindowManager(1663): WIN DEATH: Window{fd0a70b u0 com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
10-24 22:12:32.238: I/ActivityManager(1663): Process com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda (pid 22887) has died: vis  +99T 
10-24 22:12:32.238: W/WindowManager(1663): Force-removing child win Window{203d6b5 u0 SurfaceView - com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} from container Window{fd0a70b u0 com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
10-24 22:12:32.238: I/WindowManager(1663): Destroying surface Surface(name=SurfaceView - com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2045 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:897 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1460 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2635 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2614 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2593 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:1791 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:701 
10-24 22:12:32.239: D/PowerKeeper.Event(3220): notifyAMProcDied pacakageName: com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda, pid:22887
10-24 22:12:32.241: I/WindowManager(1663): Destroying surface Surface(name=com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2045 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:897 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1460 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2635 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2593 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:1791 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:701 <bottom of call stack> 
10-24 22:12:32.315: D/GameBoosterService(2606): onGameStatusChange foreground:ForegroundInfo{mForegroundPackageName='com.miui.home', mForegroundUid=10028, mForegroundPid=2146, mLastForegroundPackageName='com.DeviserSoft.SahinUzayda', mLastForegroundUid=10241, mLastForegroundPid=22887, mMultiWindowForegroundPackageName='null', mMultiWindowForegroundUid=-1, mFlags=0}
```

Comment: Create a new project, test, import assets one by one and you will find the one that make your application crash

Comment: Also you can try deleting `/TMP` and `/Library` Unity will recreate them automatically when you restart it. Then recompile your project

Comment: @LudovicFeltz thanks for answer.  i don't understand /tmp and /library. where are they?

Comment: At the root of your project. It contains files cached by unity but sometimes can make your project crash

Comment: @LudovicFeltz doesn't work. i will edit to logcat.

Comment: @LudovicFeltz empty unity project is working on the phone. but my project does'nt work. my app was working before the update. (unity 2019.2.9f1)